# Inserting into table with foreign key constraint in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

Suppose I have a table called **Actor**:

```
Actor_ID (pk) (AI), Actor_Name          // pk = primary key, AI = auto inc
```

Then I have a table called **Character**:

```
Character_ID (pk) (AI), Actor_ID (fk), Character_Name
```

Now I want to add a new **Character** to my Database.

- I check to see if the actor for this character already exists in the **Actor** table
- If it does, I get the `Actor_ID`
- If it doesn't, I add the actor to the **Actor** table, and get the `Actor_ID`
- I add the new character to the **Character** table using the `Actor_ID`

***My problem:***

When I insert a new actor, do I have to open a new connection to the database. Insert the actor. Then close the connection. Then open a new connection to insert the character.

The reason I ask this is because I'm getting the error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

when I try to add the character. I'm guessing it must be because the `Actor_ID` isn't in the **Actor** table yet.

Could someone please clarify this for me? Is there an easier way to do this than opening many connections?

Comment: Why do you need to open many connections? What's the problem with just one connection?

Comment: See **Section2 / What does Show your Schema Mean?** of [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38899465) to help us to help you. If you do that for the 2 or 3 (whatever) tables involved, we can clearly show you the data error